# How to add tests/ directory to PYTHONPATH when testing with Travis-CI?

Tags: python, testing, travis-ci, python-import

My package structure:

```
foop
|___foop
|   |___foo.py
|
|___tests
    |__test_foo.py
    |__test_helper.py
```

`test_foo.py` imports both foo and test_helper:

```
import foo
import test_helper
```

The problem is that `tests` is not in `$PYTHONPATH` so `import test_helper` raises `ImportError`.

I'm very new to Travis-CI. Could anyone please let me know how can I solve this import error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The travis `env` variable is what you're looking for.

Try adding this `yml` to your `.travis.yml`:

```
env: PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/tests:$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/foop
```